# RxJava, OkHttp, Okio, file downloader in Android

Tags: android, rx-java, okhttp

I am trying to convert this working file download code to Reactive. But got stuck, due to my little knowledge of RxJava. Could you help me to make it Reactive?

```
public void downloadFile(MessageComponent media) {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(media.getMediaUrl())
                .build();

        Call call = http_client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to execute " + request, e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                }
                String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(media.getMediaUrl());
                File file = new File(helper.getTmpFolder() + "/" + helper.generateUniqueName() + "test." + mimeType);
                BufferedSink sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(file));
                sink.writeAll(response.body().source());
                sink.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "downloadFileFromServer done: " + media.getMediaUrl());
            }
        });
    }
```

This is what I have written so far, and its not getting any result or error:

```
public void downloadFile(MessageComponent media){
   Observable<String> downloadObservable = Observable.create(
            sub -> {
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(media.getMediaUrl())
                        .build();
                Response response = null;
                try {
                    response = http_client.newCall(request).execute();
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) new IOException();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sub.onNext(response.toString());
            }
    );

    Subscriber<String> mySubscriber = new Subscriber<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(String responseString) {
            Log.d(TAG, "works: " + responseString);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    };
    downloadObservable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(mySubscriber);
    mySubscriber.unsubscribe();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code have some errors, which may explain that the expected behaviours is not what you get.

**Observable contract error**

Reactive Extensions (RxJava is an implemtation of it) is based on this contract : you can be notified multiple times on onNext then, you will notified once (or never...) on an error OR on a completion.

```
onNext* (onComplete | onError)?
```

So, your Observable code can be rewriten to this, to emit the fact that your stream is in error or that it is completed.

```
Observable<String> downloadObservable = Observable.create(
        sub -> {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(media.getMediaUrl())
                    .build();
            Response response = null;
                response = http_client.newCall(request).execute();
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    sub.onNext(response.toString());
                    sub.onCompleted();
                } else {
                    sub.onError(new IOException());
                }
        }
);
```

**Unsubscribe to earlier**

You unsubscribe just after your subscription, so your Observable may not have the time to be executed.

```
downloadObservable
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(mySubscriber);
mySubscriber.unsubscribe();
```

If the `Observable` complete, it will unsubscribe. So won't have to unsubscribe in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This question has the same final goal as the following, which is to download a file and save it to disk in Android:

[Downloading files using OkHttp, Okio and RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29838565/downloading-files-using-okhttp-okio-and-rxjava)

[Download and write a file with Retrofit and RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126793/download-and-write-a-file-with-retrofit-and-rxjava)

[Here](https://gist.github.com/lsurvila/d3c034e5ee514009e31b) is a good example for downloading a file and save it to disk in Android.

The following is a modification of the above linked example without using the lambda expression.

1.Make sure to include the necessary dependencies in your app build gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.5'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
```

2.The Retrofit 2 interface, the @Streaming for downloading large files.

```
public interface RetrofitApi {
    @Streaming
    @GET
    Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> downloadFile(@Url String fileUrl);
}
```

3.The code for downloading a file and saving it to disk using Retrofit 2 and rxjava. Update the baseUrl and the url path in the code below to your actual url of the file you need to download.

```
public void downloadZipFile() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://my.resources.com/")
            .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder().build())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create()).build();
    RetrofitApi downloadService = retrofit.create(RetrofitApi.class);

    downloadService.downloadFile("resources/archive/important_files.zip")
            .flatMap(new Func1<Response<ResponseBody>, Observable<File>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<File> call(final Response<ResponseBody> responseBodyResponse) {
                    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<File>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Subscriber<? super File> subscriber) {
                            try {
                                // you can access headers of response
                                String header = responseBodyResponse.headers().get("Content-Disposition");
                                // this is specific case, it's up to you how you want to save your file
                                // if you are not downloading file from direct link, you might be lucky to obtain file name from header
                                String fileName = header.replace("attachment; filename=", "");
                                // will create file in global Music directory, can be any other directory, just don't forget to handle permissions
                                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsoluteFile(), fileName);

                                BufferedSink sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(file));
                                // you can access body of response
                                sink.writeAll(responseBodyResponse.body().source());
                                sink.close();
                                subscriber.onNext(file);
                                subscriber.onCompleted();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                subscriber.onError(e);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<File>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted() {
                                Log.d("downloadZipFile", "onCompleted");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.d("downloadZipFile", "Error " + e.getMessage());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNext(File file) {
                                Log.d("downloadZipFile", "File downloaded to " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                            }
                       });
}
```

Comment: What if I want to return Single<File> from downloadZipFile() method? I have been trying that but don't have much experience with RxJava so not been able to do it yet.

Comment: 1. Change the void to Single<File>, 2. Add return before downloadService.downloadFile,  3 Replace the code starts from .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) till the end with .toSingle();