# Download and write a file with Retrofit and RxJava

Tags: java, android, file-io, retrofit, rx-java

I'm downloading a pdf file with retrofit, the way that i'm downloading it is by blocks. I use the `Content-Range` header to obtain a range of bytes, then i need to write these bytes on a `file` the problem is the order to write them. I'm using the `flatMap()` function to return an observable for each request that must be done to download the file.

```
.flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<Response>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Response> call(Integer offset) {
                    int end;

                    if (offset + BLOCK_SIZE > (contentLength - 1))
                        end = (int) contentLength - 1 - offset;

                    else
                        end = offset + BLOCK_SIZE;

                    String range = getResources().getString(R.string.range_format, offset, end);

                   return ApiAdapter.getApiService().downloadPDFBlock(range);
                }
            })
```

The `downloadPDFBlock` receive an strings that is needed by a header : `Range: bytes=0-3999`. Then i use subscribe function to write the bytes downloaded

```
subscribe(new Subscriber<Response>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, file.getAbsolutePath());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Response response) {
                    writeInCache(response);
                    }
                }
            });
```

But the problem is that the writing process is made unordered. For example: if the `Range: bytes=44959-53151` is downloaded first, these will be the bytes that will be written first in the file. I have read about `BlockingObserver` but i don't know if that could be a solution.

I hope you could help me.

Comment: Check `concatMap` operator http://fernandocejas.com/2015/01/11/rxjava-observable-tranformation-concatmap-vs-flatmap/

Comment: Alternatively, use a RandomAccessFile and write into the same file offset the request was made for.

Comment: You should use the DownloadManager for loading large content.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

Comment: @RalphBergmann I need download in blocks because i'm streaming the PDF with MuPDF . So while the file is downloaded i show the pages in a reader.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a good [example](https://gist.github.com/lsurvila/d3c034e5ee514009e31b) for downloading a file and save it to disk in Android.

Here is a modification of the above linked example without using the lambda expression.

The Retrofit 2 interface, the @Streaming for downloading large files.

```
public interface RetrofitApi {
    @Streaming
    @GET
    Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> downloadFile(@Url String fileUrl);
}
```

The code for downloading a file and saving it to disk using Retrofit 2 and rxjava. Update the baseUrl and the url path in the code below to your actual url of the file you need to download.

```
public void downloadZipFile() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://my.resources.com/")
            .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder().build())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create()).build();
    RetrofitApi downloadService = retrofit.create(RetrofitApi.class);

    downloadService.downloadFile("resources/archive/important_files.zip")
            .flatMap(new Func1<Response<ResponseBody>, Observable<File>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<File> call(final Response<ResponseBody> responseBodyResponse) {
                    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<File>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Subscriber<? super File> subscriber) {
                            try {
                                // you can access headers of response
                                String header = responseBodyResponse.headers().get("Content-Disposition");
                                // this is specific case, it's up to you how you want to save your file
                                // if you are not downloading file from direct link, you might be lucky to obtain file name from header
                                String fileName = header.replace("attachment; filename=", "");
                                // will create file in global Music directory, can be any other directory, just don't forget to handle permissions
                                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsoluteFile(), fileName);

                                BufferedSink sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(file));
                                // you can access body of response
                                sink.writeAll(responseBodyResponse.body().source());
                                sink.close();
                                subscriber.onNext(file);
                                subscriber.onCompleted();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                subscriber.onError(e);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<File>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted() {
                                Log.d("downloadZipFile", "onCompleted");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.d("downloadZipFile", "Error " + e.getMessage());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNext(File file) {
                                Log.d("downloadZipFile", "File downloaded to " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                            }
                       });
}
```

Comment: hey man, you are creating server api instance each time you download a file

Comment: This is for demonstration, the Retrofit instance can be moved to a global state.

Comment: You have paste as param `@Url String fileUrl` but enter path `"resources/archive/important_files.zip"`... seems method should be `@Streaming @GET({path}) Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> downloadFile(@Path("path") String fileUrl);`

Comment: What is the best way to test this solution?  It seems like tight coupling (**flatMap**, **chained operations**, **RxJava tightly integrated to Retrofit**).

Comment: how to get progress?